# How to find out these errors. My app crashed 6 times (Report from app analytics)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, google-analytics

What are these errors and how to find out these errors. In my app I am using GoogleAnalytics, Fabric, Mix panel, Core Data and I am sending parameters to the server and getting data from the server.

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)searchButton:(id)sender {

if (sender == self.searchButton) {

    Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {

        UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle : @"Message"
                                                                        message : @"No Internet!Please Connect and try again."
                                                                 preferredStyle : UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction * ok = [UIAlertAction
                              actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                              { }];

        [alert addAction:ok];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

        });

        //        NSLog(@"There IS NO internet connection");
    } else {


if ([self.selectOptionButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"Select Your Option"]) {

    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle : @"Message"
                                                                    message : @"Please select option."
                                                             preferredStyle : UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction * ok = [UIAlertAction
                          actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                          { }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

} else if ([self.textField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle : @"Message"
                                                                    message : @"Please enter number."
                                                             preferredStyle : UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction * ok = [UIAlertAction
                          actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                          style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                          { }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

} else {

    NSString * key1 = @"Something";
    NSString * key2 = @"Something";
    NSString * key3;
    if ([self.optionButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"No0"]) {
         key3 = @"0";
    } else if ([self.optionButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"No1"]) {
        key3 = @"1";
    } else if ([self.optionButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"No2"]) {
        key3 = @"2";
    } else if ([self.optionButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"No3"]) {
        key3 = @"3";
    } else if ([self.optionButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"No4"]) {
        key3 = @"4";
    }

    NSString * str;
    NSArray * arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.key4, key1, key2, self.textField.text, key3, self.systemDateTime, self.key5, self.key6, nil];

    str = [arr componentsJoinedByString:@"~"];



    self.tempURLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://hostname/%@.php?da=%@", self.string, str];



//Getting data from server through JSON approach ...
self.urlSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
self.urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.tempURLString]];
self.dataTask = [self.urlSession dataTaskWithRequest:self.urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSMutableDictionary *serverRes = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    self.integer = [[serverRes objectForKey:@"str"] count];

    if (!(error == nil)) {

        UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle : [error localizedDescription]
                                                                        message : [error localizedRecoverySuggestion]
                                                                 preferredStyle : UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction * ok = [UIAlertAction
                              actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                              { }];

        [alert addAction:ok];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

        });

 //            NSLog(@"%@", error);
    } else {

    if (serverRes == nil || self.integer == 0) {

        UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle : @"Message"
                                                                        message : @"Please enter valid number."
                                                                 preferredStyle : UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction * ok = [UIAlertAction
                              actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                              style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                              { }];

        [alert addAction:ok];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

        });

//            NSLog(@"Data Nil.....");
    } else {

        [self.array1 removeAllObjects];
        [self.array2 removeAllObjects];
        [self.array3 removeAllObjects];
        [self.array4 removeAllObjects];
        [self.array5 removeAllObjects];
        [self.array6 removeAllObjects];
        [self.array7 removeAllObjects];
        [self.array8 removeAllObjects];
        [self.array9 removeAllObjects];
        [self.array10 removeAllObjects];

    for (int i=0; i<self.integer; i++) {

        [self.array1 addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"str"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"str1"]];
        [self.array2 addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"sStr"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"str2"]];
        [self.array3 addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"sStr"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"str3"]];
        [self.array4 addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"str"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"str4"]];
        [self.array5 addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"str"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"str5"]];
        [self.array6 addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"str"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"str6"]];
        [self.array7 addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"str"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"str7"]];
        [self.array8 addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"str"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"str8"]];
        [self.array9 addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"str"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"str9"]];
        [self.array10 addObject:[[[serverRes objectForKey:@"str"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"str10"]];

    }

    //Reload tableView Data...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
    }

}
}];

[self.dataTask resume];


}
    }
}
}
```

The errors are...[image: This is first error]

[image: This is second error]

[image: This is third error]

[image: This is my fourth error]

What is the exact meaning of these error and how to solve these errors?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can create the BreakPoint to locate the error line.